# Item headers not displaying correctly in Lazy Column

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to group paginated workout items by date then display the date of those workouts in a header using `LazyColumn`. Secondly, I want to display a header only once that it used to hide the past workouts in the list, and this header should appear before the first future workout and after the most recent 'past' workout. As you can see from the images attached i'm getting strange behaviour which i believe is from using 'if' statements inside the lazy column items. Can anyone see what my issue is, or if there's a better approach to what im trying to do?

[image] [image]

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
    state = eventsListState
) {
    var lastEventStartDateTimeStamp: Long = 0

    itemsIndexed(lazyPagingItems) { index, event ->
        event?.let { event ->

            val eventStartDateTimeStamp = getMidnightTimeStamp(
                lazyPagingItems.peek(index)?.startTimeTimeStamp ?: 0
            )

            val startOfTodayTimeStamp = getMidnightTimeStamp(
                Clock.System.now().toEpochMilliseconds()
            )

            when {
                !showPastEvents.value
                        && event.startTimeTimeStamp > startOfTodayTimeStamp -> {

                    if (eventStartDateTimeStamp != lastEventStartDateTimeStamp) {
                        DisplayHeader(startDate = eventStartDateTimeStamp)
                    }

                    LiveScheduleItem(
                        event = event,
                        onClick = {
                            startActivity(
                                EventBottomSheetActivity.newIntent(
                                    requireContext(),
                                    event
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    )
                }
                showPastEvents.value -> {
                    if (startOfTodayTimeStamp in (lastEventStartDateTimeStamp + 1)
                        until eventStartDateTimeStamp
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(bottom = 24.dp, top = 28.dp)
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .clickable {

                                },
                            text = "Hide past workouts",
                            fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.josefin_san_regular)),
                            fontSize = 16.sp,
                            color = Color(0xffe6007d),
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                        )

                    }
                    if (eventStartDateTimeStamp != lastEventStartDateTimeStamp) {
                        DisplayHeader(startDate = eventStartDateTimeStamp)
                    }
                    LiveScheduleItem(
                        event = event,
                        onClick = {
                            if (eventStartDateTimeStamp > startOfTodayTimeStamp) {
                                startActivity(
                                    EventBottomSheetActivity.newIntent(
                                        requireContext(),
                                        event
                                    )
                                )
                            } else {
                                startActivity(
                                    WorkoutDetailsActivity.newIntent(
                                        requireContext(),
                                        event.workoutId,
                                        false
                                    )
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
            lastEventStartDateTimeStamp = eventStartDateTimeStamp
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to group your list by a common property, after that you can render the grouped list with a LazyColumn where the header is the key of every group.  Okay show me the code.

Assuming you have a data class

```
data class Person(val name: String, val dob: LocalDate)
```

And a list of people

```
val people = listOf(
    Person("Person 1", LocalDate.now()),
    Person("Person 2", LocalDate.now().minusDays(2)),
    Person("Person 3", LocalDate.now().minusDays(3)),
    Person("Person 4", LocalDate.now().minusDays(4)),
    Person("Person 5", LocalDate.now()),
    Person("Person 6", LocalDate.now())
)
```

You can group these people by their date of birth inside your composable

```
val peopleByDob = people.groupBy { it.dob }
```

Now you can render them inside your LazyColumn

```
LazyColumn{
    // destructured people here refers to all people who fall under one date
    peopleByDob.forEach { (date, people) ->
        // Render header composable using [date]
        item {

        }

        // Render list of [people] who have the same [date]
        items(people) { person ->

        }
    }
}
```

Output, today's date is 20th Feb, btw
[image: CFD Output but same code in Android]

Comment: As I'm using paging items, I don't get access to the groupby function

Comment: Nice Hack lol - I like